# Are there other than FFT ways to implement Guitar Tuner?

Tags: audio, fft, frequency, audio-processing, tuner

I want to do precise guitar tuner, this is usually done by many via computing FFT and getting peak. But this is of low appliance for several reasons:

- Discrete precision, gives insuffient resolution for tuning bass guitar.
- High computation time and complexity, when trying to increase buffer size(and/or sampling rate). Introduces visible delay(lag).
- Most of frequency range where concentrates all FFT's precision is unused. Everything above 1-2 khz is not appliable for tuning musical instruments.

There should be simplier way for signals that have single-frequency sinusoidal shape. Given small enough buffer (say it 256 samples with 96khz sampling rate) - how could you measure a base(lowese) frequency?

In simple words: How to find frequency `F`, so that difference of "**sine signal of frequency `F`**" and "**actually recorded signal**" would give **minimal error**, than for any frequency, other than `F` ? (so we can definetely conclude that sinusoid of frequency `F` is best approximation of recorded sound buffer).

PS. Anything, but not using FFT!

Comment: this might give you some food for thought https://mlesniak.com/post/2018/09/13/go-guitar-/-visualize-sound/  ... a bit of a tangent from my guitar notes     Show HN: Guitar Dashboard – Open source music theory explorer for guitarists - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17987657
   source article at   http://guitardashboard.com/

Comment: @ScottStensland This simplistic SDL example just renders the waveform (in time domain), this is useless, because today people are using higher-level libraries for drawing charts\graphs (with autoscaling/stacking/... features and so on), and not writing that basics themselves - it was written million times before. That was just a offtopic remark, but i mentioned that "it's useless", primarily because I dont want to draw it! Not in time domain, neither in frequency domain)) I want to find some **base frequency `F`** of the note currently playing, with good resolution at low frequencies.

Comment: Guitar note waveforms do not have a sinusoidal shape, very often not even close.  Thus a bare FFT peak is not a workable method.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Whole note waveform is not sinusoidal, but we dont require it in its "wholeness": We better drop *attack*, *release* and additional overtones, like pluck sound. What is most notable - most of the note energy is concentrated in **sustain**. And it is almost pure sine (resonant) stuff: String resonate at single frequency, which depends purely on a its tetnsion and length.

Comment: Note that 256 samples (at 96k) of any note more than a 3rd below Concert-A is less than one full cycle, which is below the 1st bin of any DFT or Goertzel like method.  So you would need an estimator of incomplete cycles for 256.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Somehow, someway.. I still have no good idea how to implement kind of "realtime" tuner, based not on some buffer. Best idea I have by now is a zero cross detector, which just counts samples passed since last zero-cross event. Any DC offset would immediately ruin it..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach based on zero crossing. It relies on being able to map the instrument signal to a simple sinuoid. This may work OK when signal to noise ratio is high, but is not a very robust method.

- Bandpass filter around the fundamental frequency of the tone you want to tune for. Example 82.41 Hz for low E string on guitar.
- Consider a window of the last N samples. Set it to ex 100ms to update the pitch estimate 10 times per second.
- Perform zero-crossing detection with a threshold value T.  T could be set to 10% of signal peak for example. Count the periods between each zero crossing, collect them in an array.
- Take the median of the periods to get your pitch estimate

You can also compute the quantiles of the periods to estimate how reliable the method is. If they give very different numbers from the median, then the method is not working well.

The approach can be extended by computing autocorrelation on the zero-crossings, as described in
https://www.cycfi.com/2018/03/fast-and-efficient-pitch-detection-bitstream-autocorrelation/

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but answer is very obfuscated for me. Can't understand what is "expected" frequency. Also what is "windowed separation into.." And what filter to use?

Comment: I have updated the explanation now, perhaps it is more clear